# Find a hidden PHP function?

Tags: php, function

So I picked up a job that requires me to fix some broken code that another programmer wrote. It's a mess and is hard to read, but what *really* gets me is that I need to find a specific function that is buried somewhere in hundreds of php files.

If you were given the function name, say `<?php print mystery_function(); ?>`, how would one go about tracking this down?

Aside from the brute method of ftping the entire site and having windows search through each file (which I am about to do), is there a way of sending a value to that function and producing an error that is traceable?

Comment: yes you should break this function to see which line the php localize it, what happen if you associate your function with error_handler("mystery_function") ? you need to force the php to be broken, as i know it wont find switch back to php error handler. it will die there....

Comment: i use ultraEdit for my IDE, it has a function feature that lists all functions. To go to the function you want you can simply just click it and it will bring you right to it on the page. Its my favorite feature.

Comment: sounds cool... I'll have to look into that.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
$reflection = new ReflectionFunction('mystery_function');
echo $reflection->getFileName();
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionfunction.php

Answer (score 2):

If you are on windows you could use [wingrep](http://www.wingrep.com/) to help you search through the files pretty quickly. As far as a solution in php itself, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

I see NOTHING "brute" in "ftping" the entire site, storing it locally and then running grep for whatever substring,
or even just SSH in and grep on-site.

This let's you find whatever substrings, such as html fragments, filenames and such, not only function names.

Do not call brute a general purpose method used by thousands programmers, you brute ;)